# Azure API Management Date Conversion

Tags: azure-api-management

Hello Azure API Management Users:

I was wondering if there is Inbound processing and Outbound processing rule I could create to change the formate of a date time. I want to standardize API date times for our partner developers (right now our backend endpoints have different date times).

Thanks for any help

Josh

Answer (score 0):

You can access payload using policy expressions as context.Request.Body.As<...> (see reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions) Using that you're free to parse your payload and process it the way you want. There is no out-of-the box policy to change date time format.